# Как написать условие чтобы 1 знак числа не был равен 2 и 3 и 4 знаку

Tags: javascript

Как написать чтобы 1 знак числа не был равен 2 и 3 и 4 Пример 1234 норм, 1214 -одинаковые, 1231-одинаковые.
Не прокатывает (rands[0] != rands[1] || rands[2] || rands[3] )

```
function randomInteger(ar) {
    ddd="одинаковые";
    rand = ar;
    rands=String(rand);
    if(rands[0] != rands[1] || rands[2] || rands[3] ){
        return rands;
    }else 
        return ddd;
}

console.log(randomInteger(1010));
```

Comment: сравните с каждым и будет вам счастие.

Comment: я знаю что так прокатит, но я думал может можно как то по другому

Comment: можно в массив запихать, можно цикл написать, можно регулярками проверить. еще как нибудь можно. но не так как у вас написано.

Comment: число только четырехзначное? какой результат ожидается при `1222`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function check(str) {
  return str.lastIndexOf(str[0]) == 0 ? 'Одинаковые' : 'Неодинаковые';
}

console.log(check('1234'));
console.log(check('1214'));
```

Comment: про длину кстати ни слова не говорилось. `12341` сюда же

Comment: @teran, не, там в вопросе сравнить `1` - я так понимаю _первый_ символ со всеми остальными, а не вообще повторения

Comment: @teran Судя по коду в вопросе, 5-значных строк там не предполагается. Но при желании, можно добавить еще проверку. `str.substr(0, 4).lastIndexOf(...` :)

Comment: @Grundy да хз, по моему 2-3-4 это не все остальные, а только 2,3 и 4й.